# Rails Routing Error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm trying to access my checkpoints#index method with this url:
`http://localhost:3000/lessons/introductions/checkpoints/`

But I get this error:

> `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"checkpoints", :lesson_id=>#<Checkpoint id: 1, checkpoint: "Definition of Monetary Policy", url: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HX3wOWN9-sM", objective: "Define monetary policy", description: "Welcome to this series of lectures on monetary poli...", question: "What is the definition of monetary policy?", hint: "It is the deliberate manipulation of something OR s...", answer: "-", lesson_id: 8, created_at: "2012-06-29 07:21:47", updated_at: "2012-06-30 08:24:15", slug: "definition-of-monetary-policy">}`

This shouldn't be the case because in my "rake routes":

```
      lesson_checkpoints GET    /lessons/:lesson_id/checkpoints(.:format)          checkpoints#index
                         POST   /lessons/:lesson_id/checkpoints(.:format)          checkpoints#create
   new_lesson_checkpoint GET    /lessons/:lesson_id/checkpoints/new(.:format)      checkpoints#new
  edit_lesson_checkpoint GET    /lessons/:lesson_id/checkpoints/:id/edit(.:format) checkpoints#edit
       lesson_checkpoint GET    /lessons/:lesson_id/checkpoints/:id(.:format)      checkpoints#show
                         PUT    /lessons/:lesson_id/checkpoints/:id(.:format)      checkpoints#update
                         DELETE /lessons/:lesson_id/checkpoints/:id(.:format)      checkpoints#destroy`
```

Wouldn't it load the #index action rather than the #show action? Does anyone know a possible reason for this error?

This is how my routes.rb looks like:

```
resources :lessons do
  resources :checkpoints
end  

resources :lessons

resources :topics do
  resources :lessons
end 

#Devise Routes
devise_for :users


resources :subjects do
  resources :topics
end
```

Comment: That sounds more like something in a view is trying to link to an action/controller/parameter combination that does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem: My friendly_id was correct. The error was in my view itself. I have defined the resources twice so I can access the url at localhost/lessons/blahblah. Which works for me. My view file needed editing (from the default un-nested one) and once it was corrected everything was working smoothly again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't mentioned routes for "introductions".

```
resources :lessons do
   resources :introductions
end 

resources :introductions do
   resources :checkpoints
end
```

Comment: I have used friendly_id for this rails app.

The name of my lesson is "introductions". navigating to http://localhost:3000/lessons/8/checkpoints/ gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. I think that there is some problem with setting up friendly_id for your lessons model.
   Your friendly_id setup is giving an object of Checkpoint as a friendly-id for your lesson, instead of title of the lesson, which is what you want from the URL given.
2. Your routes declaration is incorrect. You are declaring resources 'lessons' twice.

```
resources :lessons do  
  resources :checkpoints  
end  
resources :lessons
```

You can check the correctness of your friendly_id in console:

```
lesson = Lesson.create(name: 'introduction')
lesson.friendly_id #=> should output 'introduction'
```

Comment: I found out the problem:

My friendly_id was correct. The error was in my view itself.

I have defined the resources twice so I can access the url at localhost/lessons/blahblah. Which works for me.

My view file needed editing (from the default un-nested one) and once it was corrected everything was working smoothly again.

Comment: The first declaration of lessons will create routes  localhost/lessons/blahblah like this just as your second declaration, There is simply no need of the second declaration. You can check it out by removing it.